# Join an array using a block and not an expression in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, string

I'm trying to join an array this way:

```
@cols = (1,2,3,4); 
my $s = join("|$_", @cols);
print $s;
```

and I expect the following output:

```
1|2|3|4
```

but that doesn't work.

I was also looking for some reduce-like function but I can't find one nor I know how to write one in Perl.

Using CPAN is not an option as this program will be executed in computers I cannot install anything else.

What other similar function can I use for that purpose?
How can I write that generalized join or reduce function in Perl?

Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish here. Can you give an input and desired output.

Comment: A little more context would be useful: what is `$hr` and what do you expect `$_` to be?

Comment: Sorry, everyone. I had a long day and forgot to review my code. The array was inside a hash reference and I mixed everything. Now I am sure what I want and it is piece of cake. I mixed map with join. As map blocks declare $_ I thought join did the same. Sorry. I vote to delete this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you want:

```
my $s = join('|', @$hr{@cols} );
```

With reduce:

```
use List::Util 'reduce';
my $s = reduce { "$a|$hr->{$b}" } '', @cols;
```

(though that produces a leading |).

Comment: hash slices always confuse me, is your `join` example the same as mine with `map`?

Comment: @Joel : That's right - `@{$hr}{@cols}` will return the same list that `map { $hr->{$_} } @cols` returns.

Comment: @Zaid: except that the elements of the hash can be modified via the slice but not via the list returned by map

Answer (score 0):

[`List::Util`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aUtil) (which is core not CPAN, though you shouldn't ever give up on CPAN) provides a `reduce` function. If you provide an input / desired output perhaps I can mock up an example for you.

Looking at ysth's answer gives me another guess at what you want:

```
my $s = join("|", map { $hr->{$_} } @cols);
```

again, with more context perhaps we can help more.

Edit: As per the OP's edit, you really are just looking for the simple [`join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) function. Unlike map, it doesn't need any `$_`, it automatically joins every element.

```
my $s = join("|", @cols);
```